# Getting SCRIPT1028 error on Edge when using react lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, microsoft-edge, react-suspense

My app works on other browsers but not (on v44)
If I remove the lazy-loading, it works fine.

I am using `React.lazy` and `Suspense` to split my code.

- babel 7.5.0
- webpack 4.28.3
- react 16.7.0

Have tried messing with webpack and babel config.
It seems the error is being thrown by the following code which is inside an eval.
I think it's the spread syntax which is killing it.
However, I don't know how to get babel to transpile this into es5 as its the webpack code itself.

```
function reduce(state = {}, action) {
    return {
        dirtyHandlerIds: Object(_dirtyHandlerIds__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["default"])(state.dirtyHandlerIds, {
            type: action.type,
            payload: {
                ...action.payload,
                prevTargetIds: Object(_utils_js_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["get"])(state, 'dragOperation.targetIds', []),
            },
        }),
        dragOffset: Object(_dragOffset__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"])(state.dragOffset, action),
        refCount: Object(_refCount__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["default"])(state.refCount, action),
        dragOperation: Object(_dragOperation__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])(state.dragOperation, action),
        stateId: Object(_stateId__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["default"])(state.stateId),
    };
}
```

webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        sideEffects: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'] // loads js
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['ts-loader'] // loads ts
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] // handles css
            }
        ]
    },
    // gets it to bundle index.html
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve('./public/index.html')
        })
    ],
    // makes it able to resolve .jsx calls without explicit suffix
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    }
};
```

babel config

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/react'
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        [
            'import',
            {
                libraryName: 'antd',
                style: true
            }
        ]
    ],
    env: {
        test: {
            plugins: [
                'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Expected: works on edge just like other browsers

Actual: dies as soon as you hit something which triggers a lazy load

Comment: same behaviour on v44

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? super weird issue - i have just started running into it. Only a problem for on Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Nope @fredmoon - I gave up to be honest

Answer (score 0):

I corrected a similar issue with a webpack configuration change.

We use lazy loading in the way you described, and I ran into almost this exact issue. Thanks to this question I found a spread operator in an `eval` that Edge was rejecting.  In my case it was due our use of the `react-svg-loader`.

We were trying to bring in an svg as JSX like this:
`import Image1 from 'react-svg-loader!./image1.svg';`, which was failing on Edge with a similar error.

Converting to using the loader as part of our webpack config corrected the issue:

```
// In your webpack config
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "babel-loader"
    },
    {
      loader: "react-svg-loader",
      options: {
        jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
      }
    }
  ]
}

// In your lazily loaded component
import Image1 from './image1.svg';
```

Comment: I  don't think I'm using any weird loaders (as you can see above) - how did you track down that particular eval?

Comment: Honestly - after I read this question, I searched the transpiled bundle code for `...` and found that it was in a module that came from code wrapping an svg.  I then looked at our source and realized we were trying to load that svg at runtime with a bunch of other transpiled JS which seemed wrong to me.  Since webpack didn't know about the loader ahead of time, it was likely just pointing at whatever gobbedlygook the library was spitting out.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had same issue loading react app in Edge v44, with same error code. My dev mode browser list did not include IE.

1. Update browser list in your package.json

```js
{
  ...
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ...
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "last 1 ie version" // <- make sure this is present
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

2. Delete .cache folder in node_modules
3. Re-run the dev server